# Rails: How to setup Heroku with Redis and Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

I'm trying to get Sidekiq to work with the [Heroku Redis](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis).

I have `Heroku Redis` as an addon on my app and and have added

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C ./config/sidekiq.yml
```

to my `procfile` but when I start the worker I see this error in my logs:

```
No such file or directory - /app/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
```

How can I go about getting Sidekiq to run with Heroku Redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the pidfile line in your sidekiq.yml.

Comment: Thanks! I inherited this project and am moving it over to heroku so there are a lot of config things going on that I dont know about.